# How do I make multi level login with Permission class in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a website with 3 types of users and every type has their own role/permission. So now I am looking for a library to work with and so far I think I found https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Permission-Class the simplest one. But I don't know how to get started, particularly the login part (user A will go to page X after login, and user B will got to page Y after login, and the likes). I'm still lost after reading the documentation, especially since I am still quite new in CI.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to get started? Thanks

Comment: go straight for ion auth! the developer ben edmunds is on the codeigniter council and he keeps this library updated. https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use something rather sophisticated for just starting out.
When I was learning I used tutorials to show me how to set everything up, from the DB to the database/helper/builder class...

This really depends on how -new- you are, are you new to PHP/SQL as well as CodeIgniter? or just new to the CodeIgniter framework and fluent(enough) in Object-oriented PHP?

If you are new to both the languages and framework I would suggest starting with doing all the [codeigniter tutorials](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) (if you haven't already).

Past that, I suggest another tutorial for just a [basic login system](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/08/how-to-create-login-form-codeigniter-mysql-twitter-bootstrap.html), from there you can build permissions and groups if required. Setting a default load-to page is as simple as adding another user DB column, storing the method/view slugs required for the redirect after login using something like

```
redirect($slugFromDB)
```

Beyond that, most people here will answer questions when you post a problem you are having and the code you're having it with and suggest (mostly) helpful advice for how to overcome your difficulty, people wont write the code for you.

Comment: I am actually not that new to PHP, especially since I had been using Laravel too. There are libraries like Zizaco entrust and roman bican for user role and permission managements in Laravel. But yes I am really new in CodeIgniter. And I'm more of looking for some pointers on how to get started with making multi level login with role and permission as I mentioned above.

Comment: What you are looking at using is purely a permissions class allowing or denying access to users based on their permissions stored in session data(loaded from DB, on login... I would imagine), this would not handle who gets directed to what page on login, this would be set as a part of your user login/account module. You would then link these users permissions to a group and then allow/deny access with the permission class you are looking at. Basically, what you want and what you are looking at using seem to be 2 different things.

Comment: I know that they are two different things. I'm sorry that I didn't word it well. But basically I need more than redirecting to different pages. User A will go to page X and I need to make sure that A can't access page Y. So I need roles and permission too here. Or do you think there's a simpler solution to this? Thanks.